# Running an exe on multiple pcs on sync

Tags: batch-file, synchronization, lan, psexec

I'm trying to run an exe on multiple pcs on sync.
Im using psexec, this is what I have till now:

I have a batch file with this:

```
start psexec \\pc01 -i -s -d c:\videos360\video360.exe
start psexec \\pc02 -i -s -d c:\videos360\video360.exe
```

With this I can start the exe in the 2 pcs, but never totally on sync.

Anyone has some idea of how can I make them run more on sync?

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: There's a lot of latency in setting up each execution. You could arrange for them to be launched more or less in parallel, but even that won't be very well sync'd.  Exactly how tight does this synchronization need to be?

Answer (score 0):

First sync the clocks on both machines. You can run a script on one of them to sync to the other or have them both sync to a central time source. Then add a task to Task Scheduler on each machine to start the application at the same time.  That's about as close as you're going to get without resorting to some sort of IPC mechanism between the processes (requires source code access to video360.exe).

See

- [schtasks.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Windows time service tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/get-started/windows-time-service/windows-time-service-tools-and-settings)

You won't need psexec because schtask can be used to manage tasks on the remote machines. It would be up to your script to change the next time to fire the task, or you could setup a repetitive task that fires every minute or two and just enable/disable the task. I believe there's a one-shot option as well.